# Changing PHP version in WSL

Tags: php, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-sail

So this is my first time trying to setup Laravel Sail on Windows. I'm utilizing Docker and WSL 2. After some trial and error I manage to get it up and running. However, I've run into an issue I'm having difficult getting around. I wanted a newer PHP version as my composer installs kept erroring on low PHP version. I downloaded, installed and set up PHP 8.1 so it's recognized in Windows when I check PHP version. But when I check version in WSL it still shows an older version. See ...

```
PS C:\Users\Geoff\zbase-app> php -v

PHP 8.1.10 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2022 18:08:04) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

PS C:\Users\Geoff\zbase-app> wsl

gbuffett@DESKTOP-SVGAO49:/mnt/c/Users/Geoff/zbase-app$ php -v

PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2022 13:29:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

How do I get WSL to recognize/utilize the 8.1 PHP version instead of the 7.4 version?

```
gbuffett@DESKTOP-SVGAO49:/mnt/c/Users/Geoff/zbase-app$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli

Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

Any insight will be much appreciated as I haven't had much luck googling the issue.

Comment: We don't get a lot of information about your guest OS in WSL, but you should be able to upgrade your PHP version through you package manager inside WSL. Another way I particularly like is PHPbrew. You can use it to switch between various version on the fly. Check it out on github: https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew

Comment: Hopefully my answer below will help you out, but I've also added the [tag:laravel-sail] tag so that it gets an appropriate audience from that perspective.  Hopefully someone who sees it with more Sail expertise than me can confirm (or refute) my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, fair warning, I have very limited experience with Laravel or Sail (and most of my PHP experience is in the distant past), but if you'll look at my profile, you'll see that I do have some experience with using various developer tools with WSL and Docker.  With that in mind ...

> I'm utilizing Docker and WSL 2

Honestly and respectfully, you don't seem to be!

When you install Sail, it creates a `docker-compose.yaml` that tells Docker Compose to download all of the Docker images your Laravel application needs, *including PHP*.  You don't need to install PHP separately; nor will installing PHP locally have any impact on your Sail application.  So the `php` commands you use in your question just aren't, unfortunately, *"utilizing Docker and WSL 2."*

And Sail already comes with PHP 8.1 ...

It's entirely possible to create *Laravel* (sans Sail) applications using a locally installed PHP, but that doesn't *seem* to be what you want to do.

So let's start from the "beginning" for Sail on WSL.  Following the [Laravel Getting Started On Windows](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows) doc, install a new app ...

```
cd ~ # or whatever root directory you want to use, but it should be in your WSL2 filesystem
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

And start Sail (per the instructions that appear at the end of the installation) with ...

```
cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

The first time you do this, it's going to take a few minutes, as Sail/Docker is going to download all of the required images from the repositories, configure the database, etc.  Subsequent launches will be significantly faster.

Once your Sail app is running, start a new Terminal window with WSL2, `cd` to the example directory created above and ...

```
> ./vendor/bin/sail php --version

PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2022 09:40:11) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

Note that for Sail, you *must* run any PHP commands *through* the `sail` command itself, since that's going to call the `php` version running in your Sail app.

Also useful doc:

- [Configuring a Sail alias](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#configuring-a-shell-alias), which will shorten the command to just `sail`
- [Executing PHP Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#executing-php-commands)

Hopefully, that answers your main question, but I'll also touch on your secondary ones:

> I wanted a newer PHP version

While hopefully you no longer need a later version (since you see that Sail comes with 8.1 already), there's the implicit question of how to change your PHP version for Sail.  That's covered in [the Sail doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#sail-php-versions).  Note that Sail currently supports 8.1, 8.0, or 7.4 only.

> I downloaded, installed and set up PHP 8.1 so it's recognized in Windows

There are at least three separate "places" you could (rightly or wrongly) install PHP then:

- Windows
- Linux (WSL) (although, as alluded to in the comments, you should mention the distribution you are using when asking questions)
- Docker

When working with WSL, as a general rule you should only use the Linux version of PHP (and other tools).  That can be installed either directly in your WSL distribution or through Docker.  But you should *not* expect to be able to use the Windows version of PHP directly with Linux.

You might get it to hobble along by running it as `php.exe` (assuming that it is on the `PATH`). Windows executables must be executed using their *full name* (including extension) in WSL, since Linux doesn't traditionally have the concept of "automatically doing something based on extension".

But even then, it's a bad idea.  The main problem is that the Windows version of PHP isn't going to understand:

- Linux filesystems and paths:  `C:\Users\LaravelNewbie` isn't a valid path in WSL, and the equivalent `/mnt/Users/LaravelNewbie` isn't a valid path to a Windows application.
- Linux processes, file locking mechanisms, etc.
- Linux native code (not as much a problem with PHP)

When working in WSL, I always recommend using the *Linux* version of any development tool.  WSL/Windows interop is great, but most tools (PHP included) aren't built to support it.  There are only a few exceptions, like Visual Studio code and some of the Jetbrains applications.

As for upgrading the PHP version in your WSL distribution (which again, you shouldn't need to do for Sail), that may vary depending on the actual distribution.  The default distribution in WSL is Ubuntu, and it only includes "long term support" releases for WSL.  Those releases tend to stick with one particular version (plus security updates) of each tool for the *entire* Ubuntu release lifespan (5 years of updates for LTS).  The reason for this is that changing the PHP version, or the version of any tool, (when other tools have been tested against that version) could create new issues.

If you want to override the version of a particular tool that is installed by the system, then consider installing a new copy for your *user* (instead of the system).  There are various tools for helping with this; one being mentioned in the comments.

Other distributions, such as Arch or openSUSE Tumbleweed, are what as known as "rolling releases", where they update to new versions of tools as soon as they are available and (reasonably) tested.  Typically the versions of tools available on these rolling releases will be newer than the ones in a "Stable" release.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent breakdown. You were right, when using the Sail commands it did show PHP 8.1 and I was able to complete my composer commands without conflict. I will also be checking out the other useful docs you referenced to look into shortening my sail commands. I always seem to have issues when setting up a new development environment. I just want to write the code, but I realize I need a better big picture understanding of the environment to do that more efficiently. Thanks again for your help.